# Using $state.go to call ui-router child state

Tags: angular-ui-router

So I am trying to have a sub menu that changes the state of the child view, and I am failing.

So set up the following function to call $state.go

```
$scope.stateGo = function (state) {
    console.log("Loadting state " + state)
    $state.go(state);
}
```

And I can see on the console that the correct (or what I think is the correct state name) is called

> Loadting state board.stat

However, nothing at all seems to be happening with the actual router. If I change it so a parent state. It does work. For example, if I set it to board it works.

The files that contains the ui-views looks as follows:

```
    <div ui-view="topmenu">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="mainView">

    <div ui-view="mainView">
    </div>
    <div style="height: 100px;"> </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-offset-3 footer navbar-fixed-bottom" id="adView">
    <div ui-view="adView">
    </div>
</div>
```

The state config:

```
    .state('board', {
        url: "/view/board",
        views: {
            topmenu: {templateUrl: "views/partials/menu-board"},
            mainView: {templateUrl: "views/partials/welcome"},
            adView: {templateUrl: "views/partials/amazon-banner"}
        },
        //controller: 'testCtrl'
    })
    .state('board.stat', {
        url: "/stat",
        views: {
            topmenu: {templateUrl: "views/partials/menu-board"},
            mainView: {templateUrl: "views/partials/stat"},
            adView: {templateUrl: "views/partials/amazon-banner"}
        }
    })
```

Am I missing something, should a call to $state.go('board.stat') get ui-router to load stat into mainView? And if so, any idea why it isn't?

======================= EDIT ===================
OK, think I might be doing it wrong, but not certain how...
Changed the buttons to use ui-href

```
<a ui-sref="board.stat"  ui-sref-active="active" class="btn btn-xlarge" ><button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart fa-1x"></i><br><h6>Stats</h6></button></a>
<a ui-sref="board.quickbet"  ui-sref-active="active" class="btn btn-xlarge" ><button class="btn btn-primary btn-circle btn-xl"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-1x"></i><br><h6>Quick bet</h6></button></a>
```

So same layout as earlier, but it seems like both child states are loaded ONLY when I enter parent state.

So I added some debugging for the state using the following two functions:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error){
        console.log("State error: " + error);
    })
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoading',
    function(event, viewConfig){
        // Access to all the view config properties.
        // and one special property 'targetView'
        // viewConfig.targetView
        console.log("State event: " + viewConfig)
    });
```

But the only output I get is:

> 2 State event: mainView@ 
>   2 State event: adView@

But when I press the buttons nothing seems to happen

Comment: May be you should call `stateGo('board.stat')` instead of `ui-sref="board.stat"`

Comment: Tried that, seems like its doing the same. Found a solution thought

Answer (score 0):

Think I solved it. 
Well, I did solve it, but I'm surprised by how it works.
So the problems seems to be that I thought the child state would reload the hole set of ui-views, it does not, and trying to do so seems to do nothing. I have no clue if this is correct interpretation, or expected behaviour, but this is what worked for me.

Load parent state with all three views (named topmenu, mainView and adView) (happens automatically).
Add a new ui-view (in my case in stats.ejs loaded on mainView)

```
This is your stats and bets
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

Last thing is to ONLY update the parts of the screen you wan't, so not mainView, but targeting the new ui-view in stats.ejs

```
    .state('board.stat', {
        templateUrl: "views/partials/stat"
    })
```

And it works, just not certain if this has to do with the DOM or something, but it worked in my case